# How replace double quote string with double quote?

Tags: c#

How replace double quote string with double quote.

```
string.Replace(""InputEntity":null", ""InputEntity":xyz")

here string is "InputEntity":null to replace.
```

Comment: Try "\"InputEntity\"

Comment: myString = myString.Replace("\"\"", "\"");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *escape character* `\`, which changes the meaning of the subsequent character:

```
string.Replace("\"InputEntity\":null", "\"InputEntity\":xyz")
```

In the case of `"`, its meaning changes from "this is the end of the string" to "this is a literal quote character". The escape character itself only appears in the source code; it does not become a part of the resulting string value.